# Connect to Exchange in another domain using Redemption

Tags: exchange-server, outlook-redemption, exchange-server-2013

Is it possible to connect to Exchange server, that is in another domain, by Redemption?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use RDOSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox.